# concat of two colums in left join query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email, zend-framework

```
$select->columns(array('TableReservationId', 'TableId', 
                       'ReservationDate', 'StartTime', 
                       'NumberOfGuests', 'AdditinalInfo', 
                       'StaffID', 'MerchantId', 'cust_id'
                       )
                 );

$select->join($cus, "$dtr.cust_id=$cus.cust_id", 
                    array('cust_firstName','cust_lastName'),
                    'left');

$select->join($mer, "$dtr.MerchantId=$mer.MerchantId", 
                     array('FirstName','LastName'),
                    'left');

$select->join($staff, "$dtr.StaffID=$staff.StaffID", 
                      array('FirstName','LastName'),
                      'left');
```

this is my query i want `concat (FirstName,'' ,LastName ) as customer_name` 
`concat (FirstName,'' ,LastName ) as Employee_name` how can i do this ?

Comment: Have you seen this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799577/zend-framework-how-to-concatenate-two-columns-and-still-use-fetchpairs

Comment: yes........its for just single query/table ...but am using join multiple table and from left table column value i want to concat

Comment: What ORM are you using here? Maybe you need to dump out to a raw SQL command.

Answer (score 0):

can you not just have it in the select? such as:

```
(FirstName + '' + LastName) as Employee_Name
```